# Firebase query by specific field value

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the structure of the data. Now how can get the list of data where the  uid is equal to ZeN7PcvLeDS8ISjXmBKelk9OUbu2.

I am using Angular 14 and firebase real time database. Following the official doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data  (for crud)

[image]

I was trying to achieve this in this way. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Also above structure of the data is correct according to the types of data?

```
getall() {
  let uid = this.auth.currentUser()?.uid;
  const db = getDatabase();
  return query(ref(db, 'expenses/' + uid), orderByChild('uid')); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the expenses of a specific UID, you can do:

```
query(
  ref(db, 'expenses'), 
  orderByChild('uid'), 
  equalTo('ZeN7PcvLeDS8ISjXmBKelk9OUbu2')
)
```

So if `uid` has the correct value in your code, that'd be:

```
query(
  ref(db, 'expenses'), 
  orderByChild('uid'), 
  equalTo(uid)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank.
It will return a query result. how can I convert it in a list or array.

Comment: You pass the query to `get` or `onValue` and then use `forEach` on the resulting snapshot, as shown in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events). If you're having trouble with that, I recommend posting a new question with what you tried from that link.